# Page not found after changing to spring security 5.3.3.RELEASE

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am trying to upgrade my spring security version to 5.3.3.RELEASE. I was able to build and deploy my war file, but after I have entered my credentials in my login page, I am getting page not found for my security_check_form. Below are my codes inside the ApplicationContext-Security.xml file.

```
<security:http use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="AuthenticationEntryPoint" disable-url-rewriting="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/testing.jsp*" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <security:custom-filter position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref="normalConcurrentSessionFilter"/>
        <security:custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="ogaLoginFilter"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/testing/gwt-log" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/images*"  access="permitAll"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/css*" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login"    access="permitAll"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/signin" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/forgotPassword" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/singlesignin" access="permitAll"/> 
        <security:session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="sessionAuthenticationStrategy"/>
        <security:logout invalidate-session="true"
            success-handler-ref="normalLogoutSucessHandler" logout-url="logout"
            delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
    </security:http>

 <bean id="normalConcurrentSessionFilter"
            class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter">
            <constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
            <constructor-arg name="sessionInformationExpiredStrategy" ref="sessionInformationExpiredStrategy"/>
        </bean>
        
        <bean id="sessionInformationExpiredStrategy"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.session.SimpleRedirectSessionInformationExpiredStrategy">
            <constructor-arg value="/cusLogin/signin.cl" />
        </bean>
<bean id="ogaLoginFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
        <property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" ref="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" />
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="AuthenticationManager" />
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="AuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>
        <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="AuthenticationFailureHandler"/>
        <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/security_check_form"></property>  
    </bean>
```

I have tried with `beans:property` instead of `property`, but the issues still persists

Comment: What is the previous version of `spring-security` you were using?

Comment: Spring security version 3.2.0.RELEASE

Comment: Oh good God! You can't just skip from 3.2 directly to 5.3! Major versions usually have major breaking changes (which means breaking/changing some assumptions and/or implementations). I would suggest you first upgrade to 4.0, then to 5.0 and finally to 5.3 or check the change log for v4.0.0 and v5.0.0 and attempt to bulk upgrade. I would go with the first approach, because the second usually ends up in weird unexplainable bugs that are hard to explain/reproduce.

Comment: One thing worth looking into is the use of api that comes out of the box in spring. There are a lot of endpoints that changed from GET to POST, it could be tripping you up somewhere